# Nodejs and UNIX newbie: run node command in a cpp program

Tags: c++, bash, unix

I'd like to run a nodejs program through the `system()` function in `stdlib.h`. I can run the bash command `/usr/local/bin/node ~/some_folder/xml2js.js` in terminal, but when I ran this:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    // insert code here...
    //system("/usr/local/bin/node ~/some_folder/xml2js.js");
    system("~/some_folder/run.sh");
    std::cout << "Hello, World!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

It told me `node: command not found`.
the run.sh is below:

```
#! /bin/bash
node ./xml2js.js
```

Are there any other ways to call other programs in UNIX? And how to get the output of the command into stdout?

Answer (score 0):

Try writing the absolute path to that script. It should work.

You could try `system("/home/$(whoami)/some_folder/run.sh")` assuming that your user's home folder is in `/home`.

Also, does that script have execute permissions? Also, check the return code of system.

Comment: i am sorry, but I forgot to tell what `run.sh` is.

Comment: Did you try using full paths in the script and in `system()`?

Comment: Also, try `node xml2js.js` (without ./) in your script, if you don't want to use full paths.

Comment: it tells me `node: command not found` when i run it in xcode IDE, and a runtime error telling that a function was not found when i run it in terminal.

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger? Also, try writing pure C code just for the debugging process.